# Link to blogg-page

Tags: links, blog

Im trying out wordpress and wondering of from the theme i have installed. Im not using the blog as the start page. How do i add a link to the menu that shows the blog with posts in order of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a page, call it "Blog"
2. *Settings->Reading...* select your new "Blog" page in the drop down next "Posts page"
3. In *Appearance->Menus* find your main menu.

   1. On the left, open up the "Pages" panel
   2. Find your page named Blog
   3. Check it and click "Add to Menu
   4. Save the menu
   5. Profit